# Stack of dynamically created components

Tags: angular

In our application I have implemented a panel, where different forms can be loaded in. The panel service receives the information to load a specific form. The panel component listenes to this service and gets the news. It creates and loads the component via `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` into the host view.

Now, we need to extend that in that way, that in a form a second form might be opened and loaded into the panel. When the second form is closed, then the user should return to the first one. So I need to have a stack of the components. This is not limited to just 2 levels.

My question is this:

- Lets say I have a `Form A` and within that form, the user can open a "sub form" `Form B`.
- When I create and load `Form A`, I receive an instance of `ComponentRef<FormA>`.
- I push this `ComponentRef` of `Form A` to my stack.
- Now the user opens a "sub form". I create and load `Form B` and receive an instance of `ComponentRef<FromB>`.
- I push this `ComponentRef` of `Form B` to my stack.
- Now the user clicks "okay" on `Form B` and so `Form B` should be closed and the user should go back to `Form A`.
- I pop `Form B` from my stack and now I want to load the already existing component of `Form A` into my host view. How can I do this? Without creating the component anew?

The reason to not just include `Form B` into `Form A` is that the surrounding panel component provides features that are relevant for the forms and different for each form, like a title, different buttons that respond to the state of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do this? Without creating the component anew?

When you use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`, it will return a `ComponentRef`. You can store that in your stack.

```js
private _myStack = [];

// Add compA to view and save into the stack
const compA = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ComponentA);
this._myStack.push(compA.hostView);

// Now we detach compA from the view.
const compAIndex = this.viewContainerRef.indexOf(this._myStack.at(-1));
this.viewContainerRef.detach(compAIndex);

// then create compB, add to view and push it to the stack.
const compB = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ComponentB);
this._myStack.push(compB.hostView);
```

After user click OK on compB:

```js
const compB = this._myStack.pop();
const compBIndex = this.viewContainerRef.indexOf(compB);

// Remove compB from the view
this.viewContainerRef.remove(compBIndex);

// Add compA back to the view
const compA = this._myStack.pop();
this.viewContainerRef.insert(compA);
```